# Identifying duplicate records in SQL along with primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a business case scenario where I need to do a lookup into our SQL "Users" table to find out email addresses which are duplicated. I was able to do that by the below query:

```
SELECT
    user_email, COUNT(*) as DuplicateEmails
FROM
    Users
GROUP BY
    user_email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY 
    DuplicateEmails DESC
```

I get an output like this:

```
user_email      DuplicateEmails  
--------------------------------
abc@gmail.com   2
xyz@yahoo.com   3
```

Now I am asked to list out all the duplicate records in a single row of its own and display some additional properties like first name , last name and userID. All this information is stored in this table "Users". I am having difficulty doing so. Can anyone help me or put me toward right direction?

My output needs to look like this:

```
    user_email      DuplicateEmails  FirstName      LastName       UserID
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    abc@gmail.com   2                Tim            Lentil         timLentil
    abc@gmail.com   2                John           Doe            johnDoe12
    xyz@yahoo.com   3                brian          boss           brianTheBoss
    xyz@yahoo.com   3                Thomas         Hood           tHood
    xyz@yahoo.com   3                Mark           Brown          MBrown12
```

Comment: @SeanLange updated..using sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you could do this. Here is one using a cte.

```
with FoundDuplicates as
(
    SELECT
         uter_email, COUNT(*) as DuplicateEmails
    FROM
        Users
    GROUP BY
         uter_email
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
)

select fd.user_email
    , fd.DuplicateEmails  
    , u.FirstName      
    , u.LastName       
    , u.UserID
from Users u
join FoundDuplicates fd on fd.uter_email = u.uter_email
ORDER BY fd.DuplicateEmails DESC
```

Comment: I get this error saying "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'ab*****@alb***.com' to data type int.
"

Answer (score 0):

Use `count() over( Partition by )`, [example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92f1c76a-f619-48db-a36a-0e21aea0b919/using-count-overpartition-in-where-clause?forum=sqlgetstarted)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    UserID VARCHAR(20),
    FirstName NVARCHAR(45),
    LastName NVARCHAR(45),
    UserMail VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO @T (UserMail, FirstName, LastName, UserID) VALUES    
('abc@gmail.com', 'Tim',         'Lentil',         'timLentil'),
('abc@gmail.com', 'John',         'Doe',         'johnDoe12'),
('xyz@yahoo.com', 'brian',         'boss',         'brianTheBoss'),
('xyz@yahoo.com', 'Thomas',         'Hood',         'tHood'),
('xyz@yahoo.com', 'Mark',         'Brown',         'MBrown12');

SELECT *, COUNT (1) OVER (PARTITION BY UserMail) MailCount
FROM @T;
```

Results:

```
+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
|    UserID    | FirstName | LastName |   UserMail    | MailCount |
+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
| timLentil    | Tim       | Lentil   | abc@gmail.com |         2 |
| johnDoe12    | John      | Doe      | abc@gmail.com |         2 |
| brianTheBoss | brian     | boss     | xyz@yahoo.com |         3 |
| tHood        | Thomas    | Hood     | xyz@yahoo.com |         3 |
| MBrown12     | Mark      | Brown    | xyz@yahoo.com |         3 |
+--------------+-----------+----------+---------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM (SELECT u.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user_email) as numDuplicateEmails
      FROM Users
     ) u
WHERE numDuplicateEmails > 1
ORDER BY numDuplicateEmails DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will also work.

```
WITH cte (
     SELECT
         * 
         ,DuplicateEmails = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition  BY user_email ORder by user_email)
    FROM Users
    )
    Select * from CTE 
    where DuplicateEmails > 1
```